# How to create own maps using own database

Tags: google-maps

I want to make map of a particular region, just for education purpose.
I have gone through several web site , which tell to make maps.
like 
http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/demos/,

But i did't find the way as GOOGLE/BING/YAHOO show their maps like its graphics quality and all that its features.
i need to add features in the map like "adding a tag, show distance", as google show.
I would also like to connect it to database(My own).
I don't want to use google api, because i can't connect it with my own data base.

Answer (score 1):

I went through this before for me it was a 4 tiers application:

- Database, I used Sql Server 2008 Spatial Database.
- Map Manager application, its main objective is to import the spatial data from different sources into the sql database, and other minor objectives like (styling the map objects, edit visible zoom level of objects, ...)
- WMS, a RESTful wcf service that renders the tiles.
- Map Client Control, a silverlight control that renders the tiles from the WMS.

You can find a lot of resources on the web on how to manipulate the spatial data (read, write, search...) and for rendering tiles I used the Bing Maps Tile System

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx

And what remains is just the implementation,

- The Map Client Control requests a tile from the WMS.
- The WMS calculates the tile boundaries and retrieves the spatial data within these boundaries and render them on an image and returns it to the client.
- The Map Client Control is responsible for layouting the tiles, zooming, panning...

You can cache the rendered tiles by implementing some cache techniques.

And finally I wish you good luck.